# Implementing Multiple Sugar ORM Database

Tags: android, sugarorm

Using Sugar ORM as database in a library project. Here is a snippet from the project manifest:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="DATABASE"
        android:value="zone-db" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="VERSION"
        android:value="1" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="QUERY_LOG"
        android:value="true" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME"
        android:value="com.appzonegroup.zone.zonedata.entity" />
```

Now, when  the library is added as a dependency to a project that also wants to use sugar ORM , How should it be implemented?

I tried adding meta-data to the projects manifest also, the project wouldn't build. It result to a `ManifestMerge Error` .

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to post a comment so that is why I am posting it as an answer. I am basically trying to do the same thing but I believe that there is no way of achieving that from what I have read on their github page.